# How to find closest match for values in CSV column from a given list and add results to the next column?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with the column of numbers. In this case, check ARPU column.(Check photo)
Also, I have a list of numbers in the code and I want to find the best match for each value from column "ARPU" from the list that I have created in the code. And I want results to be recorded in the next column in CVS file

[image: Check image here]

My existing code is

```
tp_usp15 = 1500
tp_usp23 = 2300
tp_usp27 = 2700
tp_usp40 = 4000
tp_usp60 = 6000
tp_usp80 = 8000
tp_usp100 = 10000
tp_usp150= 15000
tp_usp250= 25000
tp_usp500= 50000
list_usp = [tp_usp15,tp_usp23, tp_usp27, tp_usp40, tp_usp60, tp_usp80, tp_usp100,tp_usp150, tp_usp250, tp_usp500]


tp_bsnspls_s = 600
tp_bsnspls_steel = 1300
tp_bsnspls_chrome = 1800
tp_bsnspls_bronze = 2200
tp_bsnspls_silver = 3700
tp_bsnspls_gold = 5600
tp_bsnspls_gold_plus = 7500
tp_bsnspls_platinum = 10600
tp_bsnspls_platinum_plus = 15600
tp_bsnspls_vip = 25000
tp_bsnspls_vip_plus = 50000
list_bsnspls = [tp_bsnspls_s,tp_bsnspls_steel,tp_bsnspls_chrome, 
tp_bsnspls_bronze,
            tp_bsnspls_silver,tp_bsnspls_gold,tp_bsnspls_gold_plus,
            tp_bsnspls_platinum,tp_bsnspls_platinum_plus,tp_bsnspls_vip, tp_bsnspls_vip_plus]


tp_bsnsrshn10 = 1000
tp_bsnsrshn15 = 1500
tp_bsnsrshn20 = 2000
tp_bsnsrshn25 = 2500
tp_bsnsrshn30 = 3000
tp_bsnsrshn35 = 3500
tp_bsnsrshn40 = 4000
tp_bsnsrshn50 = 5000
tp_bsnsrshn70 = 7000
tp_bsnsrshn100 = 10000
tp_bsnsrshn150 = 15000
list_bsnsrshn = [tp_bsnsrshn10,tp_bsnsrshn15,tp_bsnsrshn20,tp_bsnsrshn25,tp_bsnsrshn30,tp_bsnsrshn35,
            tp_bsnsrshn40,tp_bsnsrshn50,tp_bsnsrshn70,tp_bsnsrshn100,tp_bsnsrshn150]

common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn

import csv
with open('ROOT','r') as csvinput:
    with open('ROOT.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n')
        reader = csv.reader(csvinput, skipinitialspace=False,delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    
    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.append("Suggested plan")
    all.append(row)

    
    for row in reader:
       
        row.append(min(common_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(row[2]))))
        all.append(row)
    writer.writerows(all)
```

But it gives me error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Unfortunately, I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do. In particular, I don't think I understand what you mean when you say `I wanted to best match for each value in the column was recorded in the next column.`. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @swarles-barkley sorry for bad wording. I have updated the question. Actually, I have values in the CSV column and I want to find the closest match for each value from the give list that I have created in the code. The results (best matches) should be recorded in the next column. Help will be highly appreciated

Comment: No worries :) Ah! So am I right in understanding that the code is already finding the 'best' matches correctly and you're just needing help writing them to the next column in the CSV file? (As a sidenote, I believe `all` is a keyword in Python, so you may run into trouble naming your array 'all')

Comment: @swarles-barkley code doesnt work and it shows error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''. and yeah, I need help in creating new column too

Comment: Ah: In that case, I'll need to ask what 'best' means for your use case. Are you just searching for the number that's the _closest_ to the number from your ARPU column? The closest number _above_ the APRU number? etc.

Also, which line of code is it giving you that error on?

Comment: There should be a part of the error message explaining what line the error is from and listing the line number of that line. It should look like `File "yourfile.py", line X, in <module>
    <your code here>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: `

Comment: Sorry, I don't really give out much personal contact info on here. I assume you're running your python from a command line somewhere, right? I could probably find the line if you just copypaste everything from the part where you execute your code to the end of the error lines you're seeing

Comment: @swarles-barkley i have updated all the code, you can copy-paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your post does not contain the full value error it is difficult to debug. Regardless, I suggest using `pandas` to solve the issue:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('ROOT.csv')

def get_plan(arpu):
    return min(common_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(arpu)))
    
df["Suggested plan"] = df["ARPU"].apply(get_plan)
df.to_csv('ROOT.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
common_list = list_usp + list_bsnspls + list_bsnsrshn

import csv

with open("output.csv", mode='a+') as results:
  ourWriter=csv.writer(results, delimiter=",")
  ourWriter.writerow(["Zone","Number","ARPU","Closest Match"])
index = 0
with open("hisfile.csv", "r") as startingFile:
  reader=csv.reader(startingFile)
  for row in reader:
    if index == 0:
      index = 1
      continue
    tmpNum = row[2]
    resNum = min(common_list, key=lambda x:abs(x-float(tmpNum)))
    with open("output.csv", mode='a+') as results:
      ourWriter=csv.writer(results, delimiter=",")
      ourWriter.writerow(row + [resNum])
```

Will also work if you can't have dependencies. Ultimately, I would suggest getting more familiar with the tool you're using to run your code, as it will be extremely difficult to troubleshoot problems you're having without knowing what line number your errors come from in the future